# Stably isomorphic complex vector bundles which are not isomorphic

Tags: vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

Is there an example of complex vector bundles $E_1$ and $E_2$ which are not isomorphic but for which $E_1 \oplus \mathbb{C}^{n}$ isomorphic to $E_2 \oplus \mathbb{C}^{n}$ for some $n$?

I'm a beginner in topological K-theory and I feel confused about the definition of ring $K(X)$ of a manifold $X$. We say two bundles are equivalent if they satisfy the isomorphism relation above. I think this equivalence relation may be weaker than isomorphism, but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: It's easier to visualize what's happening over $\mathbb R$ rather than $\mathbb C$. For that, take $M$ to be the $2$-dimensional sphere, $E_1$ its tangent bundle, $E_2$ a trivial $2$-dimensional bundle, and $n=1$.  The point is that $E_1$, though not itself trivial, becomes trivial when you add a trivial line bundle, namely the sphere's normal bundle.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I know some thing basic about Chern classes, will it helps？

Comment: @AndreasBlass Your example actually help me! Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Sorry, I think for a few days but I still have no idea to connect the Chern class and the construction of counterexample.My goal is to find a vector bundle $E$ such that $E$ \oplus $\mathbb{C}^{m}=\mathbb{C}^{n}$. For exmaple, to make the first chern class vanish, we just need the condition that trace of the connection to be zero, which seems very weak.And for the higher chern class, too be honest, I dont know how to discribe when it will vanishes simply.

Comment: My initial comments were irrelevant as I thought you were asking if two bundles always become isomorphic after stabilisation (your wording was slightly strange). I have deleted my comments and edited the question to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of a stably trivial rank two complex vector bundle $E \to S^5$ which is not trivial. In particular, this provides an example with $E_1 = E$, $E_2 = \varepsilon_{\mathbb{C}}^2$ (the trivial rank two complex vector bundle), and $n = 1$.

Viewing $S^5 \subset \mathbb{C}^3$, consider the bundle $T\mathbb{C}^3|_{S^5}$. The Euler vector field is a nowhere-zero section $\sigma$ of $T\mathbb{C}^3|_{S^5}$, so it spans a trivial complex line subbundle of $T\mathbb{C}^3|_{S^5}$. Therefore, there is a rank two complex subbundle $E$ of $T\mathbb{C}^3|_{S^5}$ such that $T\mathbb{C}^3|_{S^5} \cong E\oplus\varepsilon_{\mathbb{C}}^1$. As $T\mathbb{C}^3|_{S^5}$ is trivial, $E$ is stably trivial. On the other hand, as a real bundle, $E$ is a rank four subbundle of $TS^5$ and we have $TS^5 \cong E\oplus\varepsilon_{\mathbb{R}}^1$ where the trivial line bundle is spanned by $i\sigma$; an alternative description of $E$ is $TS^5\cap i(TS^5)$ where we view $TS^5$ as a subbundle of the complex vector bundle $T\mathbb{C}^3|_{S^5}$. If $E$ were trivial, then $TS^5$ would also be trivial, but $S^n$ is parallelisable if and only if $n \in \{0, 1, 3, 7\}$, so $E$ is non-trivial.

More generally, for every $n \geq 2$, we can construct a stably trivial rank $n$ complex vector bundle $E \to S^{2n+1}$ which is not trivial. Note however that the above argument for non-triviality fails when $n = 3$, so a separate argument is needed.

Comment: I have not heardnof the "Euler vector field" before.  Would it be fair to say that the real two-plane it spans is spanned by the radial vector and one tangent to the Hopf fibers?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: The Euler vector field is the radial vector field $x^i\partial_i$, so yes. You can think of $E$ as the pullback of $T\mathbb{CP}^2$ by the map $S^5 \to \mathbb{CP}^2$.