# $K$-theory of $S^2$: spinor bundle vs tautological bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-forms, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I'm trying to understand the relationship between different generators of the $K$-theory group of $S^2$. Part of my curiosity comes from reading [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302131/chern-classes-of-generators-of-ks2n) about characteristic classes.

The $K$-theory group $K^0(S^2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. We may choose the first copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ to be generated by the trivial bundle $\varepsilon_{\mathbb{C}}^1=\mathbb{C}\times S^2$. For the second generator, there are two choices that I have seen in the literature, and I would like to understand how they relate to each other:

- The tautological bundle $H$ over $\mathbb{C}P^1\cong S^2$;
- The positive and negative spinor bundles $\mathcal{S}^+$ and $\mathcal{S}^-$ over $S^2$.

The first one is discussed in some detail [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/basic+complex+line+bundle+on+the+2-sphere) on nLab. The second one is used for example in section 2.16 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03502.pdf) by Baum and van Erp.

Let us fix a diffeomorphism $\psi\colon S^2\to\mathbb{C}P^1$. Then both $H$ and $\mathcal{S}^{\pm}$ can be viewed as line bundles over $S^2$, all with non-trivial first Chern classes I believe.

**Question 1:** Is $H$ isomorphic either to $\mathcal{S}^+$ or $\mathcal{S}^-$? Is there a canonical way to identify them, starting from a choice of $\psi$?

Looking at the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415204/isomorphism-class-of-vector-bundle-over-s2-and-the-chern-character/4415212#4415212), it seems that isomorphism classes of line bundles correspond precisely to their first Chern classes. So perhaps this boils down to:

**Question 2:** Is $c_1(H)$ always equal to either $c_1(\mathcal{S}^\pm)$? How does this depend on $\psi$?

*Comment:* I think perhaps something similar can be done for $S^{2n}$, or maybe even $S^n$ for all $n$, but for now I'm just trying to understand $S^2$. I wonder if there is a reference discussing all this.

Comment: $c_1(H)$ is the canonical generator of $H^2(S^2)$. From the comment in the MO thread you linked, it seems that $c_1(\mathcal{S}^{+})$ is also a generator of $H^2(S^2)$, so it would follow that $H$ and $\mathcal{S}^{+}$ are isomorphic. There's a potential subtlety in whether or not these generators have opposite sign; I don't see immediately how to resolve this. It seems like you can probably arrange it to work out if you allow yourself some flexibility in choosing $\psi$ since a diffeomorphism must have degree $\pm 1$.

Comment: I don't know your definitions of $S^{\pm}$, but the tautological bundle $H = \mathcal{O}(-1)$ is the square root of the cotangent bundle $T^{*}S^2\simeq\mathcal{O}(-2)$.