# $SU(2)$-bundles over four-manifolds are determined by top cells

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, principal-bundles

Suppose we have a compact oriented simply-connected four manifold $X$ and a $SU(2)$ bundle $P$ with $2$nd Chern class $=k$ over $X$.

We know $X$ have a top cell $e^4$, if we collapse all lower cells to a point to obtain a $S^4$, and denotes the collapsing map $g$.

Suppose $P$ represent by a map $h$ from $X$ to $BSU(2)$. Does $h$ factor through $g$(i.e. exist $\bar{h}$ from $S^4$ to $BSU(2)$ s.t. $h=\bar{h}·g$)?

Comment: Seems it is just because the attaching map induce isomorphism on top cohomology class.

Comment: $e^4$ is contractible, so $P|_{e^4}$ is trivial.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Sorry, here the top cell I mean collapse all lower dimensional cells to a point, I've edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are closed orientable four-manifolds and $f : X \to Y$ is a degree one map, then every principal $SU(2)$-bundle over $X$ is of the form $f^*P$ for some principal $SU(2)$-bundle $P \to Y$. This follows from the fact that principal $SU(2)$-bundles over a four-dimensional CW complex are determined up to isomorphism by their second Chern class, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/195592/21564). Note, this is no longer true in higher dimensions as the example in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4347940/39599) demonstrates.

If $f : X \to Y$ is arbitrary, then we have

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Prin}_{SU(2)}(Y) @>{c_2}>> H^4(Y;\mathbb{Z}) @>{\cong}>> \mathbb{Z}\\
@V{f^*}VV @V{f^*}VV @VV{\times\deg f}V\\
\operatorname{Prin}_{SU(2)}(X) @>{c_2}>> H^4(X;\mathbb{Z}) @>{\cong}>> \mathbb{Z}
\end{CD}$$

In particular, if $\deg f \neq 0$, a principal $SU(2)$-bundle over $X$ is of the form $f^*P$ for some principal $SU(2)$-bundle over $Y$ if and only if its second Chern class is divisible by $\deg f$. If $\deg f = 0$, then the only principal $SU(2)$-bundle over $X$ of the form $f^*P$ is the trivial one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not well versed on 4-manifolds, so hopefully I am not making any foolish mistakes:

Since $X$ is simply-connected, up to homotopy equivalence, it can be taken to have a $2$-skeleton given by a wedge of $2$-spheres. By Poincare duality, its $3$rd homology vanishes, which implies that, up to homotopy equivalence, it can be written without $3$-cells. Meaning that $X^3$ is a wedge of $2$-spheres.

Complex bundles over a $2$-sphere are classified by maps $S^1 \rightarrow SU(2)$ which are known to all be null homotopic, i.e. $\pi_1(SU(2))=0$. This means that the restriction of $X \rightarrow BSU(2)$ is null homotopic on $X^3$, which means that up to homotopy $X \rightarrow BSU(2)$ factors through $X \rightarrow X/X^3$, as you desire.

Comment: $BSU(2)$ is $3$-connected, so the same argument works even if $X$ is not simply connected.